# How to find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$.

There is a way to note that if $n>4$ then
$$0 < \frac{n^2}{n!} < \frac{n}{(n-2)(n-1)} < \frac{1}{n-3}$$
 and consequently the limit is zero. But can somebody provide another way to evaluate this limit?

Comment: If you go from $n$ to $n+1$, you add $2n+1$ to the numerator, while the denominator is multiplied by $n+1$. One of those operations is a _lot_ stronger than the other one.

Answer (score 9):

If $n\geq2$ then you can evaluate it this way:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n-1+1}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{n-1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\bigg)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\bigg)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\\
&=0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* This limit is closely related to derivatives of the power series for the exponential function.

*Solution:*

> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 z^n}{n!} = e^z (z^2+z)$ and so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n!} = 2e$. Since the series converges, we must have $\frac{n^2}{n!} \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $n^2<2^n$ for $n>5$ you can look at $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!}$. As $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!}=e^2$ by the comparison test the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!}$ must converge and therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!}=0$.